# Restrict list to group

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, groups

I have like 5 different lists on my sharepoint site. I want to know if its possible to create a group of members of that sharepoint and assign list to them. So the point of this, is only users are in the list have permissions to watch list and edit it. Is it possible to achieve this in sharepoint online? What are the steps to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is achieveable in SharePoint online.

You need to break permissions inheritance for lists, then you can grant unique permissions.

Go to list one by one->list settings->Permissions for this list->click stop inheriting permissions:

[image]

Then you can remove user permissions for the list, and then grant corresponding groups permissions for the list.

For more detailed information,  refer to the following article:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edit-and-manage-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

- Create the group and add members
- If using the classic UI: Click the LIST ribbon and List Settings. If using the Modern UI: Click the Settings menu (gear) and List Settings.
- Click Permissions for this List, and click Stop Inheriting Permissions.
- Remove any of the unwanted groups and users.
- Click Grant Permissions and add your new group.